# Spring Cloud Dataflow errorChannel not working

Tags: kubernetes, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm attempting to create a custom exception handler for my Spring Cloud Dataflow stream to route some errors to be requeued and others to be DLQ'd.

To do this I'm utilizing the global Spring Integration "errorChannel" and routing based on exception type.

This is the code for the Spring Integration error router:

```
package com.acme.error.router;

import com.acme.exceptions.DlqException;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.MessageEndpoint;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.Router;
import org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;


@MessageEndpoint
@EnableBinding({ ErrorMessageChannels.class })
public class ErrorMessageMappingRouter {
   private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ErrorMessageMappingRouter.class);

   public static final String ERROR_CHANNEL = "errorChannel";

   @Router(inputChannel = ERROR_CHANNEL)
    public String onError(Message<Object> message) {
      LOGGER.debug("ERROR ROUTER - onError");
      if(message.getPayload() instanceof MessageTransformationException) {
         MessageTransformationException exception = (MessageTransformationException) message.getPayload();
         Message<?> failedMessage = exception.getFailedMessage();
          if(exceptionChainContainsDlq(exception)) {
             return ErrorMessageChannels.DLQ_QUEUE_NAME;
          }
         return ErrorMessageChannels.REQUEUE_CHANNEL;
      }
      return ErrorMessageChannels.DLQ_QUEUE_NAME;
    }

    ...

}
```

The error router is picked up by each of the stream apps through a package scan on the Spring Boot App for each:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.acme.error.router" }
@SpringBootApplication
public class StreamApp {}
```

When this is deployed and run with the local Spring Cloud Dataflow server (version 1.5.0-RELEASE), and a DlqException is thrown, the message is successfully routed to the onError method in the errorRouter and then placed into the dlq topic.

However, when this is deployed as a docker container with SCDF Kubernetes server (also version 1.5.0-RELEASE), the onError method is never hit. (The log statement at the beginning of the router is never output)

In the startup logs for the stream apps, it looks like the bean is picked up correctly and registers as a listener for the errorChannel, but for some reason, when exceptions are thrown they do not get handled by the onError method in our router.

Startup Logs:

```
o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer : Adding {router:errorMessageMappingRouter.onError.router} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel : Channel 'errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer : started errorMessageMappingRouter.onError.router
```

We are using all default settings for the spring cloud stream and kafka binder configurations:

```
spring.cloud:
  stream:
    binders:
      kafka:
        type: kafka
        environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=brokerlist
        environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes=zklist
```

Edit: Added pod args from `kubectl describe <pod>`

```
Args:
--spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=delivery-stream
--spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.requiredGroups=delivery-stream
--spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=delivery-stream.enricher
--spring.cloud.stream.binders.xdkafka.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes=<zkNodes>
--spring.cloud.stream.binders.xdkafka.type=kafka
--spring.cloud.stream.binders.xdkafka.defaultCandidate=true
--spring.cloud.stream.binders.xdkafka.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=<brokers>
--spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=delivery-stream.config-enricher
```

One other idea we attempted was trying to use the Spring Cloud Stream - spring integration error channel support to send to a broker topic on errors, but since messages don't seem to be landing in the global Spring Integration errorChannel at all, that didn't work either.

Is there anything special we need to do in SCDF Kubernetes to enable the global Spring Integration errorChannel?

What am I missing here?

Update with solution from the comments:

> After reviewing your configuration I am now pretty sure I know what
>   the issue is. You have a multi-binder configuration scenario. Even if
>   you only deal with a single binder instance the existence of
>   spring.cloud.stream.binders.... is what's going to make framework
>   treat it as multi-binder. Basically this a bug -
>   github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1384. As you can
>   see it was fixed but you need to upgrade to Elmhurst.SR2 or grab the
>   latest snapshot (we're in RC2 and 2.1.0.RELEASE is in few weeks
>   anyway) – Oleg Zhurakousky

This was indeed the problem with our setup. Instead of upgrading, we just eliminated our multi-binder usage for now and the issue was resolved.

Comment: Apart from setting the Kafka config settings for connection/creds, we don't do anything special in K8s-server or muck around with the properties. It could be that the way how you're creating the docker container could have a side effect wrt how the properties are propagated over. See here for [`entryPoint`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes/docs/1.7.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_entry_point_style) options - it'd be good to review your `Dockerfile` and perhaps also the sample app.

Comment: if we're using the default errorChannel settings though, would that even matter? It would just be part of the default configuration (that we're not overriding in any way with runtime environment variables). Is there some other way that the entrypoint style could affect that?

Comment: by the way, we're using the exec style

Comment: Depending on what the `entrypoint` style is in use, there's a different runtime expectation on how the properties are handled. Let's start with your `Dockerfile` anyway. Other than that, when you deploy the stream via Local-server, how did you run the server? `java -jar` or `docker compose-up`? If it is the latter, did the app start successfully in the Docker daemon? Also, it'd be good to review the logs of router-app in entirely. Lastly, if you can share the output of `kubectl describe <pod>` of your app-pod, that'd help, too.

Comment: ran the local server with ```java -jar```, the router isn't a standalone app. It's a 
 shared configuration that's attached to each of the deployed apps. In the logs for the individual apps, you can see it get attached as a subscriber to the errorChannel (like the log messages in the post), but then there are no log messages from the router itself. The app that the router is deployed with functions just fine, reading from the broker and publishing to it, but on an exception, for some reason it doesn't pass that message to the errorChannel to be handled. will post the kubectl describe pod

Comment: added kubectl describe pods output to the body above

Comment: I'll try different direction. The `errorChannel` is internal to the process, actually to be more exact it is internal to the Application Context, which means there is absolutely no relation to the underlying runtime environment. Are you sure the exception is actually thrown and if it is what do you see in the logs? This should'd be hard to track

Comment: yes, the exception is thrown and can be seen in the logs. There is an @GlobalChannelInterceptor that listens to all messages as well and its "afterSendCompletion" handler is hit each time with the failed message. The default Spring Integration RetryTemplate is also executed and the message is retried a few times to that app. Is it possible that the spring integration retry stuff is interfering with the errorChannel?

Comment: @SabbyAnandan any other suggestions? This has been driving me crazy. Everything is working well within our stream except sending to the errorChannel on exception, which is a pretty simple pattern

Comment: Thanks for the "describe" output - it seems all straightforward. I had thought propagating the environment properties could have an issue depending on how the docker container is packed, but that shouldn't really interfere in this case. In other words, you aren't overriding anything at the time of stream deployment. Everything is set to the default except the connection properties perhaps. Since it is consistently happening to you, would it be possible to share a minimal version of the app?

Comment: I'll see what I can do, it'll be difficult. This is a small module in a large proprietary code base

Comment: After reviewing your configuration I am now pretty sure I know what the issue is. You have a multi-binder configuration scenario. Even if you only deal with a single binder instance the existence of `spring.cloud.stream.binders....` is what's going to make framework treat it as multi-binder. Basically this a bug - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1384. As you can see it was fixed but you need to upgrade to Elmhurst.SR2 or grab the latest snapshot (we're in RC2 and 2.1.0.RELEASE is in few weeks anyway)

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky you're the man! That was the issue. We currently are only using one of the binders in our configuration, so we removed it and used a single one and the issue was immediately resolved. If you want to post an answer and get the credit, I'll accept it. Thanks to both you and Sabby for the assistance!

Comment: I can care less about credits, the fact that I was able to help is more then enough!

Comment: Oh, Oleg is _always_ humble. Nicely done, sir! Btw, @pclem12, it'd be great if you can answer and accept it yourself, so that way others in the community can quickly get to the solution instead of parsing this lengthy chatter here. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update with solution from the comments:

> After reviewing your configuration I am now pretty sure I know what
>   the issue is. You have a multi-binder configuration scenario. Even if
>   you only deal with a single binder instance the existence of
>   spring.cloud.stream.binders.... is what's going to make framework
>   treat it as multi-binder. Basically this a bug -
>   github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1384. As you can
>   see it was fixed but you need to upgrade to Elmhurst.SR2 or grab the
>   latest snapshot (we're in RC2 and 2.1.0.RELEASE is in few weeks
>   anyway) – Oleg Zhurakousky

This was indeed the problem with our setup. Instead of upgrading, we just eliminated our multi-binder usage for now and the issue was resolved.